# I want to remove utm_referrer parameter from pages tested in Google Optimize

Tags: google-analytics, utm, google-optimize

I getting utm_referrer parameter added at the end of my url and which is causing issue in my GA and affecting the website.

I want to remove only utm_referrer parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude it in Google Analytics View settings specifying it as a parameter to remove from the URL in the dedicated textarea.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michele, will you be able to explain more about it, I am new to google analytics tool, this issue is coming for all the landing and non-landing pages, how can I exclude it for all the URLs?

Comment: Thanks Michele, I did the changes and I can still see the parameter coming in the  URL, do you know why?

Comment: If parameter is entered correctly, just wait few hours or maximum tomorrow to see today data cleaned.